# Share media directly with custom dialog on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, whatsapp

I have a kind of specific questions concerning the feasibility of sharing content (image, text, best with opengraph meta data) to specific apps or websites from my iOS App. Maybe someone has some experience with this and can help me out.

I want to share an image + text (best with opengraph meta data to link a given website) to Facebook and Whatsapp (maybe more messengers, social media platforms later on). For this I want to give the user a custom dialog with these two (or later more) options.

Now after doing some research on this topic I couldn't really find a way to do so without integrating the Facebook SDK or kind of abusing the Document Interaction API for Whatsapp. The only way seems to be using UIActivityViewController with excludedActivityTypes. openURL also doesn't seem to do the trick since it seems you cannot really share media.

Is there a way to share images to specific social media or messenger services without integrating SDKs and use a custom dialog for this?
Or do I have to use either SDKs or UIActivityViewController

And is there a possibility to use OpenGraph data alongside sharing media with the UIActivityViewController?

Thanks in advance!